# Vala - Gtk Label hover styling css

Tags: css, gtk, vala

I want to colorize gtk labels or a spesific label when hovered with mouse. How can I achieve this? I have tried something like this but it is not working:

data/style.css:

```css
/* This works: */
label {
    color:yellow;
}

/* This is not working: */
label:hover {
    color:yellow;
}
```

```
Gtk.CssProvider css_provider = new Gtk.CssProvider ();
            css_provider.load_from_resource("data/style.css");
            Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen (Gdk.Screen.get_default (), css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
```

Comment: in gtk3 only a few widgets support hover, try wrapping in a GtkEventBox and styling the label when it's hovered

Comment: yeah I made it that way. So, there is no css hover...